# Can I create a "hyperlapse" video without using After Effects?

Tags: software

I am trying to learn hyperlapse and every tutorial I have found in youtube uses After Effects software to create it. Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: This question probably will be closed becouse this site is not about video. But take a look at this tool, in my opinion it gives you great results becouse it stabilizes the path: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/hyperlapseapps/ Look for the pro version.

Comment: Whatsahyperlapse

Answer (score 2):

Not professional level at all, but the app "Hyperlapse" creates hyperlapeses. Instagram brain-child.